# Broken dependencies 12.04

Tags: 12.04, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

When I try to update or install new packages it pops up an eror message telling me that the package catalog needs repaired, I click repair and than it tells me it was unable to repair.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

initramfs-tools: Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (>= 0.99ubuntu13) but
0.99ubuntu13.1 is installed
                 Depends: klibc-utils (>= 1.5.9-1) but 1.5.25-1ubuntu2 is installed
                 Depends: busybox-initramfs (>= 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu5) but 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1 is installed
                 Depends: udev (>= 147~-5) but 175-0ubuntu9.2 is installed
                 Depends: findutils (>= 4.2.24) but 4.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
                 Depends: util-linux (> 2.15~rc1) but 2.20.1-1ubuntu3 is installed
```

and when performed '`sudo apt-get -f install`'
the output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  initramfs-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  initramfs-tools
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/49.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-bin (<< 0.99ubuntu13.1~); however:
  Version of initramfs-tools-bin on system is 0.99ubuntu13.1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth:
 plymouth depends on initramfs-tools; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing plymouth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-label:
 plymouth-label depends on plymouth (= 0.8.2-2ubuntu31); however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing plymouth-label (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 plymouth
 plymouth-label
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and I tried [Maintenance commands - AptGet/Howto - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Maintenance_commands) but it didn't work.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: This was mistakenly marked as a duplicate – it might cursorily appear to be a generic unmet dependency issue but none of the linked suggestions are relevant because it's actually a metadata bug in a security update for the initramfs-tools package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/984688

Comment: @ChrisAdams No matter *what* your opinion is, you should never remove the banner.  If you think this was wrongly closed you should bring it up on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/).  Thank you.

Comment: @Seth: it's not a question of opinion but correcting errors. That said, I flagged it for review as I don't really have an interest in a meta discussion about policy but wanted to make sure anyone else who lands on this page from a web search will find the link to the launchpad issue with the fix.

Comment: @ChrisAdams I didn't mean post on meta about policy's.  When you want a question re-opened you are encouraged to post a question on meta about it, explaining your reason.  Flagging also works.  Correcting errors is always fine, but when it comes to closed questions that should be done on meta.

Comment: @ChrisAdams Also, if you post a meta question it probably get re-opened faster.  Example question [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/4015/44179).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enough free space in /boot. In my case I got rid of exactly the same error message by purging old kernel images via Synaptic Package Manager.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this answer (by editing) to explain *how* to check free space in `/boot`.